# How to load all values of particular attributes in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1.9. We can use below code to load all values of particular attributes

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'brand');

    if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
        return $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    }
```

How to do the same in Magento 2.4 version?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution & working fine for me. If anyone has still the best or short solution can answer.

put below code on a constructor of any helper or block class.

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttribute
    ) 
 
    {
        $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    }
```

**Put below function in helper or block file.**

```
 public function getBrandListing()
    { 
        $brand = $this->_eavAttribute->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'brand');
        $allOptions = $brand->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        return $allOptions;
    }
```

Now call the getBrandListing function from any file by creating the object of helper.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
  protected $_eavAttribute;
    
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttribute
    ) {
        $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    }
    
    public function getManufacturerListing()
    { 
        $manufacturerAttr = $this->_eavAttribute->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer_name');
        $allOptions = $manufacturerAttr->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        return $allOptions;
    }
```